# How to isolate SR-IOV Virtual Fuctions which are bind to DPDK igb_uio driver in docker container from each other

Tags: docker, dpdk

I was recently trying to bind SR-IOV VF pci devices to DPDK app  in docker container, the expect scenario : each docker container runs DPDK application which take charge of one sriov VF. But DPDK application can see all sriov VF ports, and this will cause different docker container can handle other VF which may charged by another container.

the steps are:

**(1) enable SR-IOV function, Virtual Functions are setup correctly** 
#lspci
04:10.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01) 
04:10.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01) 
04:10.5 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01) 
04:10.7 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01)

**(2) run two docker containers** 
#docker run --privileged --name="sriov_test" -v /mnt/huge:/mnt/huge -itd centos:latest

**(3)bind VF port to igb_uio drv** 
#./dpdk-devbind.py -s 
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver 
============================================ 
0000:04:10.1 '82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function 10ed' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbevf,vfio-pci 
0000:04:10.3 '82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function 10ed' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbevf,vfio-pci

**(4)run dpdk application my_basicforwd** 
#./my_basicfwd -l 1 --log-level 8  -- -p 1 
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s) 
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes 
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket 
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB 
EAL: Probing VFIO support... 
EAL: VFIO support initialized 
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:1f.6 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:15b7 net_e1000_em 
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe 
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.1 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe 
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:10.1 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10ed net_ixgbe_vf 
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:10.3 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10ed net_ixgbe_vf 
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:10.5 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10ed net_ixgbe_vf 
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:10.7 on NUMA socket -1 
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10ed net_ixgbe_vf

timer period 33120229810 
debug nb_ports 2 
Port 0 MAC: 02 09 c0 4b b4 a7 
Port 1 MAC: 02 09 c0 3c ce 0f

Above shows that dpdk can see two VF ports, another container dpdk application result is same.
I was trying to set the VF ports to docker container's netns by : ip link set xxx netns xxx, unfortunately no use.

I was searching for a long time on net, but no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this, thanks a lot.

Comment: please update with the following information, Kernel Version, DPDK version, Os distro, NIC firmware, Flow director rules for redirecting traffic.

Comment: thanks for your response, kernel version is Linux version 5.4.0-70-generic, dpdk-stable-18.11.11,  docker client and server engine 19.03.11, Intel 82599ES NIC. I haven't send traffic yet. Thanks

Comment: please update the question, and also update the firmware version of NIC

Comment: once you bind a NIC to dpdk drivers like `uio_pci_generic|igb_uio|vfio-pci` there are no longer maintained with Kerenl or namespace. So for a DPDK port to be used or not used you should be using option `-w|-b` for DPDK 18.11.11. I am not able to see the same with DPDK application, can you please set the same and check the same?

Comment: this is NIC version: # ethtool -i enp4s0f1
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.1.0-k
firmware-version: 0x00012b2c, 1.1197.0
my question is:  the dpdk application in two different docker container can see  the same  Virtual Functions,   the dpdk applictions may take over the others VFs, this is unexpected,  it can not make VF resources isolated, thanks.

Comment: this is the expected behaviour because `docker run --privileged `. Docker runs on top of current kernel and resources, it is only in Virtual Machine hypervisor partitions the resource. So please use option `-w|-b` in each docker to ensure there is no overlap.

Comment: please let me know the result of running with DPDK option `-w|-b`. If it works for you I will update with details as answers. Thanks

Comment: thanks, without --privileged, the dpdk applications seems can not runs well

Comment: one can either remove prioveelge or give specific folder priveelge  for DPDK ports. That is `/dev/uio/device-1` or `/dev/vfio/device-1`, this will ensure each device is under each docker instance and not all

Comment: “give specific folder priveelge for DPDK ports” what do you mean, I am not clear about this, I bind two VF ports, crw -- root root /dev/uio0 and crw -- root root /dev/uio1, could you describe more details, thanks a lot

Comment: I tried dpdk option -w ,  like: ./my_basicfwd -l 1 -w 0000:04:10.1 --log-level 8  -- -p 1, the result is OK, this is very useful, thanks a lot. By the way, could you describe “give specific folder priveelge for DPDK ports” more details, it will very helpful for me, thank you.

Comment: @VipinVarghese  some good advice from you ?,remove  prioveelge  have trouble too. thanks [66904937](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904937/running-dpdk-in-docker-container-without-privileged)

Comment: thanks, could you offer some advice for another question :[66904937](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904937/running-dpdk-in-docker-container-without-privileged)thanks.

Comment: I have a look into the same and update as necessary. If the current answer has helped please feel free to accept and upvote.

Comment: are you not trying to do same in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904937/running-dpdk-in-docker-container-without-privileged? should I check

Comment: It is me who created issue 669049737 to trace

Comment: so do I need to check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note: Based on clarification in the comments, setting the expectation for Docker/Container vs Virtual Machine instances.

- Docker or container runs on top of existing kernel and hardware resources. The isolation is done in Kernel namespace and CPU|Memmory|File access privileges
- In the virtual machine, the hardware like CPU|Memory|NIC (physical and virtual devices) are partitioned into separate instance. The guest OS is the separate kernel that runs the devices with its drivers. Host OS has no access to the guest devices

**So when a DPDK application runs inside a docker/container, it has access to huge page, /dev/, and drivers just like a standalone application.** one has to restrict the access to a physical device using `allow/block in DPDK 20.11 onwards` and `whitelist/blacklist in 20.08 and below`.

Hence following are the possible solution for running DPDK inside container/dpdk

1. if docker/container is run with full privilege, use option `-a or -b for DPDK 20.11 onwards` or `-w or -b for DPDK 20.08 and below`.
2. if docker/container is run with selected privileges, use `chown` to change the ownership to desired user account for DPDK device bound with `uio_pci_generic\igb_uio` under `/dev/uio` or `vfio-pci` under `/dev/vfio/`. This will limit access to the devices when DPDK is run with `non sudo` mode

note: please first make sure to run in non `sudo` mode on the host, then identify the changes to be done in an environment variable, huge page access, /dev/. Then start the docker with right user under the desired name space.

Comment: I tried the solution 2, run docker/container with non sudo mode, unfortunately, get wrong response from  EAL: Cannot open /sys/class/uio/uio0/device/config: Permission denied

Comment: @happy who is owner for uio0? is it same user as DPDK application?

Comment: requires live debug, with current information is not clear what is the issue.

Comment: could you share your docker run  configurations without privileges  which can run DPDK l2fwd,  it may be useful , thank you very much.

Comment: @happy I have shared the details of what I had done in Docker with DPDK 18.11 LTS. Since the debug details are insufficient I have a request for live debug.

Comment: could I add you skype or teams account, 690111350@qq.com is my teams account. thanks

Comment: send request to the id  690111350@qq.com  via skype